# how to fill missing time slots in python?

Tags: python, pandas, deep-learning

I'm trying to fill the missing slots in the CSV file which has date and time as a string.

My input from a csv file is:

```
A               B               C

56  2017-10-26 22:15:00     89
2   2017-10-27 00:30:00     54
20  2017-10-28 05:00:00     64
24  2017-10-29 06:00:00     2
91  2017-11-01 22:45:00     78
62  2017-11-02 15:30:00     99
91  2017-11-02 22:45:00     34
```

Output should be

```
A               B               C
0   2017-10-26 00:00:00     89
1   2017-10-26 00:15:00     89
.
.
.
.
.
56  2017-10-26 22:15:00     89
..
.
.
.
.
96    2017-10-26 23:45:00   89
0   2017-10-27 00:00:00     54
1   2017-10-27 00:15:00     54
2   2017-10-27 00:30:00     54
.
.
.
20  2017-10-28 05:00:00     64
21  2017-10-28 05:15:00     64
.
.
.
.

24  2017-10-29 06:00:00     2
.
91  2017-11-01 22:45:00     78
.
62  2017-11-02 15:30:00     99
.
91  2017-11-02 22:45:00     34
```

The output range is 15 min time slots for days between 2017-10-26 -> 2017-11-02 and each day have 96 slots.
And the same as above.

Comment: So could you tell us what you have already tried and where you got stuck exactly?

Comment: Regargind your title : Checkout datetime , and dateutil library. It might be a start. If you are stuck trying to use those , edit this question to reflect your attempt.

Comment: I've posted an answer that does the required transformation for columns B and C. I'm not sure I understand your logic with A entirely. Do you keep the values, and in new records you just add 1..N? So in your example the A number before 56 will possibly not be 55?

Comment: @perl I guess `A` is the ordinal number of the 15 minute interval in the day. So `B==00:00:00` gives `A=0`, `B==00:15:00` gives `A=1` and so on.

Comment: @QuangHoang: Well spotted! Looks exactly that way! I've updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

Using `resample` to get 15-min intervalsand `bfill` to fill missing values in `B`:

```
df = df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df.pop('B')))
df.loc[df.index.min().normalize()] = None
df = df.resample('15min').max().bfill()

df['A'] = 4*df.index.hour + df.index.minute//15

print(df)
```

Output:

```
                      A     C
B                            
2017-10-26 00:00:00   0  89.0
2017-10-26 00:15:00   1  89.0
2017-10-26 00:30:00   2  89.0
...                  ..   ...
2017-11-02 22:15:00  89  34.0
2017-11-02 22:30:00  90  34.0
2017-11-02 22:45:00  91  34.0
```

Comment: According to the example provided by the op, this shouldn't be ``bfill``.

Comment: Honestly, it's a little unclear, the first C value in the original dataset at `2017-10-26 22:15:00` is 89 and all the C values in the outcome before that value are 89, so it's backfilled. What happens next in the example is some sort of combination of `bfill` and `ffill` though

Answer (score 0):

You need to resample your data and to fill missing values by propagating the last known value for each date. Pandas could be helpful to do that. Assuming you loaded your csv in pandas (with `pandas.read_csv`), and you obtained a dataframe (let's call it `df`) where the date column is your index (`df.set_index('B')`), then:

```
df.resample(rule='15M').ffill()
```

The `rule` parameter defines the new frequency, and the call to `.ffill()` means "forward fill", i.e., replace missing data with previous ones.